# Rails 5: loading static assets from a yarn package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, vue2-dropzone

I'm currently using vue2-dropzone for a Rails 5 project. I've installed it with `yarn add vue2-dropzone`. The package includes its styles from the **rollup.config.js** file, as such:

```
export default {
  moduleName: 'vue2Dropzone',
  entry: 'src/index.js',
  dest: 'dist/vue2Dropzone.js',
  format: 'umd',
  sourceMap: true,
  plugins: [
    vue({
      compileTemplate: true,
      css: 'dist/vue2Dropzone.css' // Here we are :)
    }),
    ...
  ]
};
```

While this is displaying correctly for other users, Rails or Webpacker doesn't seem to pick those assets up (i.e. `vue2Dropzone.css`).

How does Rails/Webpacker load dependencies or static assets? Why wouldn't this file be loaded?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to configure `config/webpack.yml` and include the path to the assets. See [this](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/README.md#paths). I've been creating separate packs for these types of components and then adding them to the erb's separately from application pack.

Comment: I tried this with a number of combinations but can't seem to get it working yet :-/